# Exception while using JavaBean in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I can't solve this problem can you help me please.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<jsp:useBean id="musteri" class="beanler.MusteriBean" scope="request" ></jsp:useBean>

<%musteri.setIsim("Ferid");%>
<%=musteri.getIsim() %>
</body>
</html>
```

> EXCEPTION: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with
>   path [/Servlet_Projesi] threw exception [/beanTest.jsp (line: 11,
>   column: 0) The value for the useBean class attribute
>   beanler.MusteriBean is invalid.] with root cause
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /beanTest.jsp (line: 11, column: 0)
>   The value for the useBean class attribute beanler.MusteriBean is
>   invalid.

```
package beanler;

public class MusteriBean {
    private String isim;
    private String soyad;

    public String getIsim() {
        return isim;
    }
    public void setIsim(String isim) {
        this.isim = isim;
    }
    public String getSoyad() {
        return soyad;
    }
    public void setSoyad(String soyad) {
        this.soyad = soyad;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set the property by using `<jsp:setProperty>`

```
<jsp:useBean id="musteri" class="beanler.MusteriBean" scope="request" >
<jsp:setProperty name="musteri" property="isim" value=" Ferid" />
</jsp:useBean>
```

while displaying you can use `<%=musteri.getIsim() %>`

Answer (score 1):

Two points you can give a try.

[1]Initialise your class properties like

```
private String isim = null;
private String soyad = null;
```

[2][Not mandatory]implement Serializable like

`public class MusteriBean implements java.io.Serializable`

Comment: Thanks @RaviG that is work. But can you explain why we did this change?

Comment: This is not what made it work. My guess is that changing the source code triggered a recompilation in Eclipse, which triggered a redeploy in the server, which made the class available to the JSP. Your code was fine from the beginning (except scriptlets should not be used anymore for more 10 years). The default value of a non-primitive field is null. Initializing them to null just adds noise.

Comment: @JB Nizet No. When you are initialising bean, it expects the class properties to be initialised.

Comment: They are initialized to null by default. This is specified in the Java Language Specification: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html#96595

Comment: @JBNizet Yes it might be a building issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also found another solution.

```
<jsp:useBean id="musteri" class="beanler.MusteriBean" scope="request" ></jsp:useBean>
```

I changed it to:

```
<jsp:useBean id="musteri" class="beanler.MusteriBean" scope="request" />
```

and that works..